# How to set default Region padding?

Tags: java, css, javafx

All my buttons and things are too close to their boundaries so I am trying to set the default padding of `Region`. I found [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#pane) link which describes to me the style to use, `-fx-padding`. I want to set this as the *global* instead of setting it for every single thing I make. I tried to make this css file and add it to my scene, but it didn't seem to work:

```
.region{
  -fx-padding: 5px
}
```

Setting it in code:

```
getDerbyDisplayStage().getScene().getStylesheets().add("com/neonorb/derbypro/ui/gui/Style.css");
```

I didn't get any error message in the console (which does exist if I change the path).

Could there be some order of doing this? Do I have to set the style sheet before I add components and things? If this is the case, I would have to separate the scene making from the components as I am using FXML to create my Stage, Scene, and components.

Comment: Even if you could do this, you wouldn't want to.  The style of all of the default controls are based upon regions, so if you managed to set a default padding for regions, then no controls would render correctly.

Comment: I think you *can* do this, but as @jewelsea points out, you don't want to. The css `.root, .root * { -fx-padding: 10px }` will set the padding of the root element and all child nodes of the root element (i.e. everything) to 10 pixels. Since only `Region`s understand `-fx-padding`, you'd get the effect you describe.